# How to treat black stem-tips and leaf-veins in Mango?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, mango

The plant in question is a Mallika grafted onto Gomera. It is planted in a fabric pot with general purpose potting soil and resides outdoors in a sunny spot while being protected from the rain.

Unfortunately, it's in close proximity to various Citrus trees that tend to attract lots of insects (predominantly mealybugs). For that reason, the plant is regularly inspected for pests (thrips being the most common).

About 3 months ago its health began deteriorating: leaves curving upward/downward and/or inside/outside, brown/black spots on leaves and leaves abscising. Lately, the primary vein of some leaves and some stem tips gradually got black, as can be seen in the following photos.

**Black stem-tips**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Black leaf-vein**

[image]
[image]

Affected leaves slowly dry up and eventually drop. The blackening of the stem tips seems to progress quite slowly, if at all.

Is there anything that can be done to avert further damage?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like fungal infection from the photos. If that is true, similar brown patches with yellowish borders, like those visible in the mango leaves, should be present in the citrus leaves nearby. The fungal infection is likely to be more extensive in the citrus trees compared to the mango plant.

The infection can be treated with various copper based fungicides. Along with applying anti-fungal solutions, the infected leaves and twigs in both the citrus trees and the mango plant should be pruned and removed away to limit the spread of the disease.